# Confused with how example contract successfully calls external contract

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to learn Solidity and I came across the following 2 contracts:

https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps/blob/master/contracts/45_pong.sol
https://github.com/fivedogit/solidity-baby-steps/blob/master/contracts/45_ping.sol

The contract `pong` holds some value, and the contract `ping` is supposed to be able to access this value via the `getPongvalTransactional` function.  I'm confused with how this function works (disclaimer: I have no background in object oriented programming).

If I understand correctly, in the `ping` contract, all contracts of type `PongvalRetriever` contain a function called `getPongvalTransactional` which returns `-1`.  The `pong` contract address is declared to be a contract of type `PongvalRetriever`.

However, the pong contract also contains a function called `getPongvalTransactional` which returns the actual value we want.  In following line of the ping contract

```
function getPongvalRemote() 
{
    pongval = pvr.getPongvalTransactional();
}
```

why does `pongval` equal the actual pong value instead of -1?

Comment: `pongval` on the left of`=` is the variable that will receive the value on the right of `=`. On the right we have `pvr`, which is another instance which offers certain methods. One such is `getPongvalTransactional()`, which retrieves `pvr`'s `pong` value, which in turn can have any value. You need OOP understanding to study Solidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technique called **method overriding**. Essentially, every subclass (in this case derived contract) of `PongvalRetriever` will contain by default a function `getPongvalTransactional`, which returns -1.

However, if a subclass, in this case the `Pong` contract, defines a method with the same name, that method "overrides" the superclass's method, so the method defined in `Pong` is what is actually executed.

Then, in the `Ping` contract, `getPongvalRemote` sets `pongval` to the return value of `getPongvalTransactional`, which should not be -1. The -1 is used to indicate an error, i.e. the function is for some reason not defined, so that 0 can be used as a legitimate value.

Not that `pongval = pvr.getPongvalTransactional()` is not making a statement about the equality of the two expressions, but is setting the value of `pongval` to the value of the right side of the expression.

Comment: I'm too new to upvote, but thank you!  I have one other question: why do we need to go through the hoops of creating getPongvalTransactional() in the first place?  The whole point is to access the pongval in pvr, so why can't we just do pongval=pvr.pongval? (and add whatever analogous error checking to PongvalRetriever)

Comment: You should be able to upvote now. If you have another question, please ask it in [a separate thread](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). :-)